# Lilypond: Controlling beaming with partcombine

Tags: lilypond

I would like to find a way to reproduce:

[image: Desired]

using `\partCombine`. My current progress looks like:

```
upperVoice = \relative {
  \partCombineApart c'8[ \partCombineAutomatic f]
}

lowerVoice = \relative {
  c'8 d
}

\new Staff \with {
  printPartCombineTexts = ##f
} {
  \new Voice {
    \partCombine \upperVoice \lowerVoice
  }  
}
```

Which results in:

[image: Result]

I know how to do get what I want with [manual voice manipulation (lilybin)](http://lilybin.com/pm9uvz/2), but I am hoping there is a way to get `\partcombine` to produce this result as maintenance is much easier if each voice is in its own variable.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish? Both notations are technically incorrect — or at least highly unusual.

Comment: I'm in the position of needing to reproduce an existing vocal score, and don't necessarily have the option of making adjustments to the notation.

Comment: Then could you post an image of the score with additional context, or maybe a link to the full score? By itself, the notation doesn't make sense, even knowing it comes from a vocal score.

Comment: The full score doesn't add any information that's not provided, and the example is simplified. It's a Soprano/Alto fragment of a 4-part choral score where both voices have a unison C on the downbeat, and divide into D/F on the second half of the beat. I understand the notation is weird, but I'm not looking for ways to change it.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, change lowerVoice to add `\stemUp \hide Flag \shiftOff` before the `d`.

```
lowerVoice = \relative {
  c'8 \stemUp \hide Flag \shiftOff d
}
```

So...

```
theHack = { \stemUp \hide Flag \shiftOff }

upperVoice = \relative {
  \partcombineApart c'8[ \partcombineAutomatic f]
}

lowerVoice = \relative {
  c'8 \theHack d
}

\new Staff \with {
  printPartCombineTexts = ##f
} {
  \new Voice {
    \partcombine \upperVoice \lowerVoice
  }  
}
```